# change bootstrap 4.2 carousel duration

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, carousel

How do i change the carousel transition or fade duration in BS4.2 in scripts?
The BS doc says this:

> **Change transition duration**
>
> The transition duration of `.carousel-item` can be changed with the `$carousel-transition` Sass variable before compiling or custom styles if you’re using the compiled CSS. If multiple transitions are applied, make sure the transform transition is defined first (eg. `transition: transform 2s ease, opacity .5s ease-out`).

I am using css. can I change the transition using js?
e.g. similar to the way I change the interval:

```
<script>
    $( '.carousel' ).carousel( {
        interval: 6000
    } )
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi @dandan no you can modify that by JavaScript but you can change that in your custom CSS

for example with:

```
.carousel-item {
  transition: transform .3s ease-in-out,-webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out
}
```

Answer (score -1):

yeah, it should work. did you try to check with this code? and if you tried with this one, is it showing any error?

Comment: The code i wrote is for the interval and yes, it does work.
It is NOT for the transition duration.
I need the code for the transition duration.

Comment: so what is the proper syntax to modify the transition duration?

Comment: I don't think you can change that using js in bootstrap. as they defined transition in css. so it should be editable through that. if you want to change the transition time using js, then you need to call setInterval function. reference. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp